# How to insert a text in the last row and in a specific column of an csv file using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to insert a text in the last row and in a specific column of a csv file, I already search on the internet but I don´t find any solution.

In the example below I just want to add an email.

Example:

```
Name, Age, email
Jake, 23, jake@gmail.com
Camila, , Camila,outlook.com
, , ABC@gmail.com   <- The line that I want to add
```

my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
df.to_csv(str(day) + '_' + str(month) + '_' + str(year) + '.csv', 
          sep=',',
          header=True,
          index=False)
df.loc[df.shape[0], 'Campaign'] = 'hi'
```

Comment: It didin´t work to me, nothing was added to my file.

Comment: I did this:                                                                                                                      df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
df.to_csv(str(day) + '_' + str(month) + '_' + str(year) + '.csv',
          sep=',',
          header=True,
          index=False)
df.loc[ df.shape[0], 'Campaign'] = 'hi'

Comment: Now the file wasn´t created.

Comment: Check the answer i've posted. I confirmed that the file is created in a desired way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `to_csv` as a last line:

```
header = ["Name", "Age", "email"]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)

df.loc[df.shape[0], 'email'] = 'ABC@gmail.com'
df.to_csv("stackoverflow.csv", 
          index=False)
```

Output:

```
Name,Age,email
,,ABC@gmail.com
```